# How to use the file of github?

Tags: python, github

I am a novice in the field of machine learning, looking for some papers related to machine learning on the Internet and the codes on github are attached to the papers, and I want to execute these codes.

After downloading the program, there are many python files in it, I am very confused and don't know how to execute this file.Do I need to put all the files in the same python file and let it execute?

[image]

Comment: Hello, read the file `README` | `README.md`, usually, inside of it you can understand how to install, configure and execute the project.

Answer (score 1):

Usually we run the **main.py** file which will be referencing to the other files. you don't normally need to restructure the files as it is intended by the original author.

Comment: This is a reasonable speculation, but the guidance to read the `README`, as suggested in a comment, is better advice.

Comment: @tripleee Agreed